# Strange behavior from CMake when importing a STATIC library

Tags: c++, cmake, static-libraries

I'm experiencing a strange (bug?) when importing the yaml-cpp static library with CMake.

main.cpp

```
#include "yaml-cpp/yaml.h"
```

CMakeLists.txt (working)

```
add_library(yaml-cpp ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/path/to/libyaml-cpp.a)
target_link_libraries(main yaml-cpp)
```

CMakeLists.txt (not working)

```
add_library(yaml-cpp STATIC IMPORTED)                                
set_target_properties(yaml-cpp PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/path/to/libyaml-cpp.a)  
target_link_libraries(main yaml-cpp)
```

When I use the second CMakeLists.txt, my main.cpp cannot find yaml-cpp/yaml.h. When I use the first CMakeLists.txt, it can, however, I get the "ar: no archive members specified" message every time I configure the project, which is annoying. Would like to import it the second way to get rid of that message.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For both of you who answered, I appreciate it. Turns out I should have provided more information in my question. The issue was arising basically from the fact that I am attempting to create a portable installation, with the entire source of each of the dependencies within the project folder-structure, which is something that I haven't attempted before. It seemed logical to me that the library files (.a, .dylib, etc..) would contain all of the headers within them, but apparently that is not the case. I will provide a few details on how I was able to fix the issue.

1. Building the libraries before the rest of the project was the right move, but I forgot to install them. cmake -> make -> make install

BuildLibraries.txt (cmake file)

```
    set(yaml-cpp_cmakelists "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external/yaml-cpp-master")
    set(yaml-cpp_build_location "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/external/yaml-cpp-master")        
    file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${yaml-cpp_build_location})  

    execute_process(                                                                     
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -S ${yaml-cpp_cmakelists} -B ${yaml-cpp_build_location} -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY} -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${yaml-cpp_build_location}
        RESULT_VARIABLE result
    )
    if(NOT result EQUAL 0)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "Failed to configure yaml-cpp")
    endif()

    execute_process(                                                                     
        COMMAND make -C ${yaml-cpp_build_location} -j4
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${yaml-cpp_build_location}
        RESULT_VARIABLE result
    )
    if(NOT result EQUAL 0)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "Failed to generate yaml-cpp")
    endif()

    execute_process(                                                                     
        COMMAND make install -C ${yaml-cpp_build_location} -j4
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${yaml-cpp_build_location}
        RESULT_VARIABLE result
    )
    if(NOT result EQUAL 0)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "Failed to install yaml-cpp")
    endif()
```

2. Inside project-root directory CMakeLists.txt:

   - ensure that find_package() knows where to look for the libraries that you installed using set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ...)
   - go ahead and use find_package(). It is, as these users suggested, much easier.

CMakeLists.txt (in root project directory)

```
       cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26.0)                           
       set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
       set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

       set(REBUILD_LIBS ON)                                             # choose wether to rebuild libraries during the generate phase

       set(PROJECT_BINARY_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build")              # root build directory
       set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")      # static libraries
       set(CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
       set(CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR})
       set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")      # shared libraries
       set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")      # executables
       set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH                                            # define search-paths for find_package()
           "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/lib/cmake"
       )  

       if(REBUILD_LIBS)
           include(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/CMakeFiles/BuildLibraries.txt)   # Build external libraries using the BuildLibraries.txt CMakeLists.txt file
       endif()


       project(myProject)     
       add_executable(main main.cpp) 

       find_package (yaml-cpp)

       target_link_libraries(main yaml-cpp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first snippet doesn't make sense.

The second one is missing `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property.

```cmake
add_library(yaml-cpp STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(yaml-cpp PROPERTIES
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "<path/to/includedir>"
    IMPORTED_LOCATION "<path/to/static_lib>"
)
```

But as mentioned in an answer, why don't you use `find_package()` since yaml-cpp provides a CMake config file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of  "`add_library(yaml-cpp ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/path/to/libyaml-cpp.a)`" being a valid usage of `add_library`. see [the docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html). You *can* use absolute paths to library binaries in [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html#overview) (but I'd consider that an antipattern here and I'll explain why).

I'm pretty sure the problem is that you haven't done `target_include_directories(yaml-cpp INTERFACE <path to include directory for yaml-cpp>)` (or equivalently, set [the `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` target property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html)).

But I'd suggest you just use [`find_package`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#command:find_package). From what I see [in yaml-cpp's CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt), it does create a find-config script. Build and install yaml-cpp, and then call `find_package(yaml-cpp ...)`, which will make available the `yaml-cpp::yaml-cpp` target with correct configuration for include directory options and import location.